# Double free after setting pointer to NULL

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, double-free

Note: this may appear as a duplicate to a prior question I had asked. I have taken the comments on that question to produce a more concise and runnable version.

I have patched the memory leaks as pointed out in a prior post. Now, I am receiving a *double free* error. I have commented where I believe the *double free* error is occurring - within the `power_arr()` function. I have posted another question, operating the `trim()` function utilizing the same pattern, without receiving an error. I am trying to understand the exact cause of the *double free* error, as the management of the pointer `tmp` within `power_arr()` appears sound.

The exact error message is as follows:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000017a5fc0 ***
Aborted
```

The purpose of the code is to handle large integers as an array of integers. More specifically, to handle integers in the range of 2^1000.

Side note, the function `pad()` and the enum `SIDE`. Given the array `int n[] = { 1, 2 };`. Calling `pad()` with `SIDE` set to `LOW`, i.e. 0, and a `new_length` of 5, the array returned is as follows; { 0, 0, 0, 1, 2 }. If the `SIDE` were set to `HIGH`, the result would be { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0 }.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX(a, b) (a > b) ? a : b
#define MIN(a, b) (a < b) ? a : b

enum SIDE { LOW, HIGH };

int *pad(int *n, int nlength, int new_length, enum SIDE side);
int *sum(int *n, int nlength, int *m, int mlength, int *sum_length);
int *power_arr(int *n, int nlength, int exp, int *res_length);
int *trim(int *n, int nlength, int *res_length);
void copy(int *to, int *from, int length);

int main(void)
{
    int b[] = { 2 };
    int r, i;
    int *rlength, *res;

    r = 0;

    rlength = &r;

    res = power_arr(b, 1, 4, rlength);

    printf("Length = %d\n", *rlength);

    for (i = 0; i < *rlength; i++)
    {   
        printf("i = %d\n", res[i]);
    }

    free(res);

    exit(0);
}

int *pad(int *n, int nlength, int new_length, enum SIDE side)
{
    int i, j;
    int *padded;

    if (nlength < 1 || new_length <= nlength)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    padded = calloc(new_length, sizeof(int));

    if (!padded)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (side == LOW)
    {
        j = new_length - 1;

        for (i = (nlength - 1); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            padded[j--] = n[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < nlength; i++)
        {
            padded[j++] = n[i];
        }
    }

    return padded;
}

int *trim(int *n, int nlength, int *res_length)
{
    int i, j;
    int *res;

    for (i = 0; i < nlength; i++)
    {
        if (n[i] > 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    *res_length = (nlength - i);

    res = malloc(sizeof(int) * (*res_length));

    if (!res)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    j = 0;

    while (i < nlength)
    {
        res[j++] = n[i++];
    }

    return res;
}

int *sum(int *n, int nlength, int *m, int mlength, int *sum_length)
{
    int i, tmp, carry, padded;
    int *result, *trimmed, *op1, *op2;
    enum SIDE side = LOW;

    if (nlength == mlength)
    {
        op1 = n;
        op2 = m;
    }
    else if (nlength > mlength)
    {
        op1 = n;
        op2 = pad(m, mlength, nlength, side);
        padded = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        op1 = m;
        op2 = pad(n, nlength, mlength, side);
        padded = 1;
    }

    result = malloc(sizeof(int) * (MAX(nlength, mlength) + 1));

    if (!op1 || !op2 || !result)
    {
        if (padded)
        {
            free(op2);
        }

        free(result);
        return NULL;
    }

    carry = 0;

    for (i = (MAX(nlength, mlength)) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        tmp = op1[i] + op2[i] + carry;

        if (carry > 0)
        {
            carry = 0;
        }

        if (tmp >= 10)
        {
            carry = tmp / 10;
            tmp = tmp % 10;
        }

        result[i + 1] = tmp;
    }

    if (padded)
    {
        free(op2);
    }

    if (carry > 0)
    {
        result[0] = carry--;
    }

    *sum_length = (MAX(nlength, mlength)) + 1;

    trimmed = trim(result, *sum_length, sum_length);

    free(result);

    return trimmed;
}

void copy(int *to, int *from, int length)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        to[i] = from[i];
    }
}

int *power_arr(int *n, int nlength, int exp, int *res_length)
{
    int *tmp, *rt, *bufp;
    int bufp_length, i, dbg_i;

    rt = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);
    bufp = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);

    if (!rt || !bufp)
    {
        free(rt);
        free(bufp);
        return NULL;
    }

    copy(rt, n, nlength);
    copy(bufp, n, nlength);

    *res_length = bufp_length = nlength;

    while (--exp > 0)
    {
        for (i = *n - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            tmp = sum(rt, *res_length, bufp, bufp_length, res_length);

            if (!tmp)
            {
                printf("tmp was null\n");
                exit(-1);
            }

            copy(rt, tmp, *res_length);

            if (tmp)
            {
                free(tmp); // double-free error occurs here, on subsequent iterations
                tmp = NULL;
            }
        }

        copy(bufp, rt, *res_length);
        bufp_length = *res_length;
    }

    free(bufp);

    return rt;
}
```

Note, I would have deleted the original question that this one evolved from, but I feel this is a branch off from my "*Malloc returning same value - no double free error*" question. As subsequent debugging in that question lead to this one.

Comment: There's a lot of code here, but it looks like `sum` could free its first or third argument without the caller of `sum` knowing about whether it had or not. Thus, one of those could get freed more than once. As an aside, this logic is a little convoluted with respect to dynamic memory memory management. You should rethink it a bit and try to simplify.

Comment: @lurker. I will re-code the logic and try to simplify it. As far as the memory management. No function will `free()` a value passed to it as a parameter. The portion you are referring to in `sum()` is freeing the pointer returned by `pad()`, only if `pad()` is called. Essentially, `pad()`, `trim()`, `sum()` and `power_arr()` return pointers obtained by a call to `malloc()`. Which point, the calling function simply *frees* said pointer. There is no *freeing*, as far as I can see, of pointers passed to a function.

Comment: Well.... `power_arr` calls `sum` with `bufp` as the 3rd argument. `sum` has a case where it might free `bufp`. And then at the end of `power_arr` you have a `free(bufp)`. That seems to contradict the rule you just mentioned.

Comment: @lurker. Are you referring to the `else if (nlength > mlength)` clause within `sum()`? The statement `op2 = pad(m, mlength, nlength, side);`, assigns a new pointer to `op2`, obtained from `pad()`. Which point, `free(op2)` should not *free* `m`, which is `bufp` in this case. The only calls to *free* within `sum()` are `free(op2)` and `free(result)`.

Comment: i don't know what you want but `bufp` is `m` and `op2`, in sum() where if(padd) free(op2); here the problem, delete it and it works

Comment: the second if(padded)free(op2); delete it!

Comment: Just so I understand this. If `pad()` calls `malloc`, and returns that value. How does `op2 == m`? They we're both obtained by separate calls to `malloc`. I understand that `m` is `bufp`, but how is `op2` also bufp? op2 contains a copy of the data in `m`, which is `bufp` in this case, but it is padded and placed in a separate memory location in `pad()`.

Comment: if (nlength == mlength) {
  op1 = n;
  op2 = m;
}

and `m` is `bufp` !

Comment: I just realized that padded was undefined in the case of `nlength == mlength`. I've updated the code to initialize `padded = 0`. Which has fixed the runtime errors.

Comment: to avoid a double `free()` problem, after passing a pointer to `free( xPtr );` the next line needs to be: `xPtr = NULL;   `free()` properly handles a pointer that contains NULL, with causing any error

Answer (score 2):

`padded` was undefined in `sum()`. By initializing `padded` to zero, the `free()` logic executes correctly.

Comment: @M.M Removed, my apologies.